# Admob not receiving ads (started randomly, no known changes)

Tags: java, android, admob, logcat, ads

I noticed this evening that my apps are not generating any more ad requests tonight. This is unusual. It has now been several hours of admob not showing any new ad traffic.

So I attempted to coax my app into loading an ad and it would not. Checking the logcat shows this:

```
adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/s
dk-core-v40.js"></script><script>
.........
</head><body></body></html>
```

This has the "Ads" tag and much more information contained.

Then I get this in the logcat (also with the "Ads" tag:

```
AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
```

and finally:

```
onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

Any ideas? It's not just my device (tried on several), and others are clearly not receiving ads (number of impressions is not increasing this evening). I certainly have a working network connection on my devices (and no, adblocker is not installed).

This started randomly; I did not update my application. I did not change anything within Admob. Is it possible Admob is simply having a brief outage?

Let me know if I can provide any more information please. Thanks!

Comment: Please log into admob website and see if there is some message waiting for you. Sometimes admob upgrades to a new version of api and if you dont recompile you app with the new version, then admob stops serving ads.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I don't see anything showing up on admob's website. I assume I would see this on apps.admob.com?

Comment: I meant this website http://www.admob.com/my_sites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem - however it seemed to be miraculously fixed around 40 minutes ago so I guess Google must have fixed it.  So that means about 12 hours with no ads served.

Comment: Confirmed! Fixed here too! Yes I think about 12 hourse down.

Comment: Fixed for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here! All my apps are using standalone admob jar but one (this is using the new play service lib). The one with the new lib is the only one that is showing banners without any problem.
So, I suspect is a Google's servers related problem. The deadline for the old standalone admob jar is August 1, so I guess is a "working in progress" from Google.

Comment: It looks like it's working now. Ate you saying we must update the admob lib of we want to keep serving ads after august 1?

Comment: Yes admob standalone jar is declared as deprecated: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.it/2014/02/since-joining-google-play-services-back.html